# Time Range on a week and day view

Tags: fullcalendar

The product I am talking about is Adam Shaws Plugin Fullcalendar

I am really pleased with this product. However I am not a code expert. I am using this calendar to display bookings. However the time rows display form 12 am onwards. Realistically I only need to show the table of entries from 8am to 10.oopm. I was wondering if this could be achieved and free up some more space to make the existing rows bigger, to enhance the display of event bookings.

Answer (score 34):

Try using the agendaDay view with this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  minTime: "07:00:00",
  maxTime: "21:00:00"
});
```

> **minTime**: Determines the first
>   hour/time that will be displayed, even
>   when the scrollbars have been scrolled
>   all the way up.
>   http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/
>
> **maxTime**: Determines the last hour/time
>   (exclusively) that will be displayed,
>   even when the scrollbars have been
>   scrolled all the way down.
>   http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/maxTime/
>
> also maybe helpful: **firstHour**:
>   Determines the first hour that will be
>   visible in the scroll pane.
>
> Integer, default: 6 Values must be
>   from 0-23, where 0=midnight, 1=1am,
>   etc.
>
> The user will be able to scroll
>   upwards to see events before this
>   time. If you want to prevent users
>   from doing this, use the minTime
>   option instead.
>   http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/firstHour/

Comment: The timeformat is no longer accurate, see the answer below.

Comment: Works great now and the added documentation in yellow is an added bonus.

Answer (score 17):

I guess it works for some version

But for me it only works like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
minTime: "07:00:00",
maxTime: "21:00:00",
});
```

And big Thanks @orolo, you enlightened me.

Answer (score 7):

Another update. Latest version 5 uses this syntax to allow restriction of the times shown:

```
...
slotMinTime: "07:00:00",
slotMaxTime: "21:00:00",
....
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of fullcalendar,  the 'firstHour' property is now 'scrollTime'. The value that you use assign it should have the '06:00:00' format.

Comment: Thx.. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

for v6.1.x

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  // only show from 9am to 5pm
  slotMinTime: "09:00:00",
  slotMaxTime: "22:00:00"
}
```